# Prophecies referring to the final redemption

Tags: messiah, prophecies, messianic-redemption

What lines of neviim are generally understood as referring to the final redemption (as opposed to the return in the 2nd temple period)?

Comment: That's probably a huge list, but [Yeshayahu 11](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15942#showrashi=true) may be one of the more famous ones.

Comment: Can we make this a wiki?

Comment: Is a better question how do chzal decide what's for all time and what's for the specific time?

Comment: @andrewmh20 No need! דון יצחק אברבנאל already did! See below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don Yitzchak Abarbanel wrote a book that is the answer to this question. He organizes all of the prophecies in Tana"ch that he holds to be foretelling *Mashi'ach* by person, starting with Bil'am, in משמיע ישועה ([*Mashmi'a Y'shu'a*](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19481&pgnum=1)).

Here is [the outline](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19481&st=&pgnum=7), but read the full book for his argumentation and proofs.

**1st Harbinger - Bil'am:**

- נאם בלעם בנו בעור וכו

**2nd Harbinger - Moshe:**

- למען ירבו ימיכם וכו
- ואם ירחיב ה' א-להיך את גבולך וכו
- והיה כי יבאו עליך כל הדברים וכו
- הלא הוא כמוס עמדי וכו

**3rd Harbinger - Y'shayahu:**

- באחרית הימים נכון יהיה וכו
- הנה האדון ה' צבאת מסעף פארה וכו
- הוי ארץ צלצל כנפים וכו
- משא מצרים הנה ה' רוכב על עב קל וכו
- הנה ה׳ בוקק הארץ ובולקה וכו
- ארח לצדיק מישרים וכו
- קרבו גוים לשמוע וכו
- נחמו נחמו וכו
- כה אמר ה׳ לבזה נפש למתעב גוי וכו
- שמעו אלי רודפי צדק מבקשי ה׳ וכו
- רני עקרה לא ילדה וכו
- קומי אורי כי בא אזרך וכו
- שוש אשיש בה׳ תגל נפשי וכו
- כה אמר ה׳ כאשר ימצא התירוש באשכול וכו
- כה אמר ה' השמים כסאי והארץ הדום רגלי וכו

**4th Harbinger - Yirmiyahu:**

- שובו בנים שובבים נאם ה' וכו
- הוי רועים מאבדים ומפיצים וכו
- כתב לך את כל הדברים אשר דברתי אליך אל ספר וכו
- מצא חן במדבר אשר היה אל ירמיהו וכו
- ועתה לכן כה אמר ה' א-להי ישראל לעיר הזאת וכו
- ויהי דבר ה' אל ירמיהו שנית והוא עודנו עצור וכו

**5th Harbinger - Y'chezkel:**

- בן אדם אחיך אחיך אנשי גאולתך וכו
- והעולה על רוחכם וכו
- בן אדם נהה על המון מצרים וכו
- הנני אני ודרשתי את צאני ובקרתים וכו
- בן אדם בית ישראל יושבים על אדמתם וכו
- היתה עלי יד ה׳ וכו
- ואתה בן אדם קח לך עץ א' וכו
- בן אדם שים פניך אל גוג וכו
- ובהפילכם את-הארץ בנחלה וכו
- כה אמר ה' א-להים זה גבול אשר תתנחלו וכו

**6th Harbinger - Hoshe'a:**

- תחלת דבר ה' בהושע וכו

**7th Harbinger - Yo'el:**

- והיה אחרי כן אשפוך את רוחי על כל בשר וכו

**8th Harbinger - Amos:**

- הלא כבני כושיים אתם לי בני ישראל וכו

**9th Harbinger - Ovadya:**

- The whole book

**10th Harbinger - Micha:**

- והיה באחרית הימים יהיה הר בית ה' וכו
- אל תשמחי אויבתי לי כי נפלתי קמתי וכו

**11th Harbinger - Chavakuk:**

- The whole book

**12th Harbinger - Tz'fanya:**

- לכן חכו לי נאם ה' ליום קומי לעד וכו

**13th Harbinger - Chagai:**

- בשביעי בעשרים ואחד לחדש היה דבר ה' וכו

**14th Harbinger - Z'charya:**

- ראיתי הלילה והנה איש רוכב וכו
- ויהי בשנת אחת לדריוש וכו
- משא דבר על ישראל וכו
- הנה יום בא לה' וחולק שללך בקרבך וכו

**15th Harbinger - Mal'achi:**

- הוגעתם ה' בדבריכם ואמרתם במה הוגענו וכו

**16th Harbinger - David:**

- למנצח משכיל לבני קרח כאיל תערוג וכו
- שפטני א-להים
- למנצח לבני קרח על עלמות
- למנצח לבני קרח מזמור כל העמים
- לאסף הודינו לך א-להים וכו
- לאסף נודע ביהודה א-להים וכו
- לאסף רועה ישראל האזינה וכו
- לבני קרח רצית ה' ארצך וכו
- הללו את ה' כל גוים וכו
- הודו לה' כי טוב כי לעולם חסדו וכו
- בשוב  ה' את שיבת ציון וכו
- רבת צררוני מנעורי וכו

**17th Harbinger - Dani'el:**

- ואלו צלם חד שגיא וכו
- בשנת חדא לבלשאצר וכו
- בשנת שלש לבלשאצר המלך חזון נראה אלי דניאל וכו
- שבעים שבעים נחתך על עמך וכו
- ובעת קץ יתנגח עמו מלך הנגב וישתער עליו מלך הצפון וכו

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about all of Navi, this question is probably too broad. If you are looking for a concise answer, it can be seen in the Mishnah Torah but it isn't dealing with "Navi" exclusively. It's dealing with a "nevuah".

http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188356/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-11.htm

Anyone who does not believe in him or does not await his coming, denies not only the statements of the other prophets, but those of the Torah and Moses, our teacher. The Torah testified to his coming, as Deuteronomy 30:3-5 states:

God will bring back your captivity and have mercy upon you. He will again gather you from among the nations... Even if your Diaspora is at the ends of the heavens, God will gather you up from there... and bring you to the land....

These explicit words of the Torah include all the statements made by all the prophets.

Reference to Mashiach is also made in the portion of Bilaam who prophesies about two anointed kings: the first anointed king, David, who saved Israel from her oppressors; and the final anointed king who will arise from his descendants and save Israel in the end of days. That passage Numbers 24:17-18 relates:

'I see it, but not now' - This refers to David;

'I perceive it, but not in the near future;" - This refers to the Messianic king;

'A star shall go forth from Jacob' - This refers to David;

'and a staff shall arise in Israel' - This refers to the Messianic king;

'crushing all of Moab's princes' - This refers to David as II Samuel 8:2 relates: 'He smote Moab and measured them with a line;'

'decimating all of Seth's descendants' - This refers to the Messianic king about whom Zechariah 9:10 prophesies: 'He will rule from sea to sea.'

'Edom will be demolished' - This refers to David as II Samuel 8:6 states 'Edom became the servants of David;'

'Seir will be destroyed' - this refers to the Messianic king as Ovadiah 1:21 prophesies: 'Saviors will ascend Mount Zion to judge the mountain of Esau....'